# Writing a parser which deals with big XML files, how to encapsulate data of downloaded files?

Tags: java, string, jvm, memory-efficient

I'm developing a parser which deals with big XML files, it can be 100 files constantly, and every file around 15MB. Then I parse it by using [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) library.

At the beginning I made a decision upon downloading convert it to `String`, but later I understood that it will be wrong. First of all I convert it later to `InputStream`, to be parsed by **XOM** and second reason is [Java String Pool](http://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool) so, for every XML file I actually double amount of memory it uses.

But now I doubt is it right to store downloaded data in `InputStream`? Possible there're another approaches which I don't know about?

Thank you.

Comment: Try with STax parser.

Comment: Actually you say that I don't even need to keep object in memory, I can parse it on the fly?

Comment: You can even zip them and process zip on the fly.. you won't be able to use threading tho...

Comment: @Shriram, ok. I've read a little (I didn't know that there're different approaches for parsing XML) and it looks that I can use for SAX, I need only read XML and I understand that it's simpler than using StAX, am I right? Thank you.

Comment: You misunderstand the string pool. The only strings that automatically go into the pool are constant strings that appear in Java programs (or are otherwise produced by the compiler, e.g. an expression like `"a"+"b"` probably puts `"ab"` in the pool). The only other way to put a string into the pool is by asking for it by using the `String#intern` method. So the strings you produced would not end up in the pool.